# What does jQuery.bind("mouseover.someOtherString") mean?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking at some legacy code that includes

```
someJqueryObject.bind("mouseover.someOtherString", function() ...)
```

What does it mean to add the ".someOtherString" qualifier to the eventType?  I can't find documentation of the expected behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are [namespaced events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names).

From the documentation for [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> An event name can be qualified by **event namespaces** that simplify removing or triggering the event. For example, "`click.myPlugin.simple`" defines both the myPlugin and simple namespaces for this particular click event. A click event handler attached via that string could be removed with `.off("click.myPlugin")` or .`off("click.simple")` without disturbing other click handlers attached to the elements.

In summary, it's a good practice to namespace your event bindings when you're creating a plugin (although the practice comes in handy elsewhere too).

This way you can safely remove event handlers with a certain namespace without accidentally removing any handlers that were *not* added by your plugin.